# "INSERT INTO .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" Only inserts new entries rather than replace?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, insert, duplicates

I have a table, say table1, which has 3 columns: id, number, and name.
id is auto_incremented.

I want to achieve an sql statement which inserts entries into a table, but if the row already exists, then ignore it.

However,

Every time I run:

```
INSERT INTO table1( number, name) 
VALUES(num, name) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE number = VALUES(number), 
       name = VALUES(name)
```

It seems to ignore rows with matching number and name values and appends entries to the end of the table no matter what.

Is there anything I can do to prevent this? I have a feeling it has something to do with having the auto_incrementing primary key?
thanks

Comment: you have never `DUPLICATE KEY` because you never try to insert any `id`, so it is always new and unique :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a unique composite index on number and name.

```
Alter table table1 Add unique index idx_unq(`number`,`name`);
```

Then do an `Insert Ignore INTO table1(number,name) VALUES(num, name);`

That should prevent duplicate from being inserted into the table.

[Useful link on Unique indexes](http://www.sitepoint.com/use-unique-indexes-mysql-databases/)

Comment: Thanks, I kept my insert statement to keep the  'on duplicate key' but adding the alter table query made it work seamlessly!