# Removing Duplicate Rows From MySQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I have this MySQL database setup:

```
+--------------------+----------+
| email              | password |
+--------------------+----------+
| example@gmail.com  | xxx      |
| example2@yahoo.com | xxx      |
| example@gmail.com  | xxx      |
+--------------------+----------+
```

I want to delete the duplicate row(s) where email AND password are the same.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: `email` and `password` *are* columns.  I assume you mean "rows".

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ah, yes, my apologies.

Answer (score 2):

While you have already populated your table and Gordon's answer is amble for your current situation and possibly the fastest solution, to prevent from entering duplicates in the future you should:

create a unique (composite) index on the column(s) that you wish to be unique.    In your case your sql would look something like:

```
Alter table yourtablename 
add unique index idx_unq(`email`,`password`);
```

Then do an `INSERT IGNORE INTO` instead of an `INSERT INTO`. This will ignore any duplicate future entries from populating in the table.

This post may also help you.

["INSERT INTO .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" Only inserts new entries rather than replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180903/insert-into-on-duplicate-key-update-only-inserts-new-entries-rather-than-re/28181062#28181062)

Comment: You might want to check the latest versions of MySQL.  This approach is basically deprecated (and in fact is removed in 5.7.4): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html.

Comment: It says `As of MySQL 5.7.4, the IGNORE clause for ALTER TABLE is removed and its use produces an error.` It doesn't say it is removed for `insert`, which is your use case here. this answer looks like it'll be fine for 5.7.4: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html. Basically you wont be able to use the old trick of `alter ignore add unique ...` to delete dupes.

Comment: @pala_ . . . The point is that the `alter table` removes the duplicates *with the `IGNORE` keyword*.  This is no longer allowed in 5.7.4, so the duplicates will not be removed; instead the statement will generate an error.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I understand the concept. Your comment however does not apply to this situation because the `ignore` modifier is present on the `insert` statement, not the `alter`. If run on the existing table the `alter` will fail in this case because of duplicate keys, not because of a removed feature in 5.7.4

Comment: @BK435 it does. the logic is sound provided the table is duplicate free when the `alter table` is run.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have no id column, one way is to create a temporary table and re-insert the data:

```
create temporary table tempt as
     select distinct email, password
     from yourtable;

truncate table yourtable

insert into yourtable(email, password)
    select email, password
    from tempt;
```

EDIT:

_pala has a good point.  You can prevent this problem with:

```
create unique index idx_table_email_password on table(email, password)
```

I would also advise you to include an auto-incremented primary key.  However, the question was about removing duplicates from an existing table, not the best structure for the data at hand.

Comment: If you're going to truncate the table, you may as well add the unique constraint to it to prevent dupes from re-occurring.